# kivy synchronize each Scroll_y

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

If there are two ScrollView widgets And I want to synchronize each Scroll_y.
In my code, even when scrolling in Scroll_A it does not move itself and Scroll_B does not move in real time.
What kind of code should I write to synchronize Scroll_y with these two ScrollViews in real time?

```
python
from kivy.app            import App
from kivy.lang           import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties     import ObjectProperty

class Scroll_A(ScrollView):
    scroll_b = ObjectProperty(None)
    def on_scroll_move(self, touch):
        self.scroll_b.scroll_y = self.scroll_y

class Scroll_B(ScrollView):
    def on_scroll_move(self, touch):
        pass

Mykv = '''
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    spacing: 100, 100
    padding: 50, 50, 50, 50
    Scroll_A:
        id: scroll_a
        scroll_b: scroll_b
        do_scroll_y: True
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            color: 1,1,1,1
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text: 'X' * 1000
    Scroll_B:
        id: scroll_b
        do_scroll_y: True
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            color: 1,1,1,1
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text: 'Y' * 1000
'''

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(Mykv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

```
#python
from kivy.app            import App
from kivy.lang           import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties     import ObjectProperty

class Scroll_A(ScrollView):
    scroll_b = ObjectProperty(None)
    pass

class Scroll_B(ScrollView):
    pass

Mykv = '''
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    spacing: 100, 100
    padding: 50, 50, 50, 50
    Scroll_A:
        id: scroll_a
        scroll_b: scroll_b
        do_scroll_y: False
        scroll_y: self.scroll_b.scroll_y
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            color: 1,1,1,1
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text: 'X' * 10000
    Scroll_B:
        id: scroll_b
        do_scroll_y: True
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            color: 1,1,1,1
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text: 'Y' * 10000
'''

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(Mykv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bind property of ScrollView for Scroll_y and Scroll_x, here I have 3 ScrollViews able to scroll horizontally and vertically simultaneously.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties     import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup 


class root(BoxLayout):


    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(root,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'
        self.size_hint=(1,1)
        self.size=(Window.width,Window.height)
        self.ptheader = BoxLayout (orientation='horizontal',size_hint=(1,None),height=100,pos_hint= {'top':1})
        self.add_widget(self.ptheader)
        self.crnumber = Label(text='Cr Number', size_hint=(0.5,None),height=100)
        self.name = Label(text='Name',size_hint=(0.5,None),height=100)
        self.ptheader.add_widget(self.crnumber)
        self.ptheader.add_widget(self.name)
        pttextheader= BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal',size_hint=(1,None),height=100,pos_hint= {'top':1})
        self.add_widget(pttextheader)
        crnumbertxt = Label(text='20201',size_hint=(0.5,None),height=100)
        nametxt = Label(text='Bo ganesh',size_hint=(0.5,None),height=100)
        pttextheader.add_widget(crnumbertxt)
        pttextheader.add_widget(nametxt)

        mainwindow = BoxLayout(orientation= 'horizontal',size_hint=(1,0.95))
        self.add_widget(mainwindow)

        self.titlescroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(0.2,None),size=(300,Window.height-250),do_scroll= True)
        self.titlescroll.bind(scroll_y=self.my_y_callbacktitle)
        mainwindow.add_widget(self.titlescroll)
        titlebox = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=10, spacing=10,size_hint=(None, None), width=300)
        titlebox.bind(minimum_height=titlebox.setter('height'))
        self.titlescroll.add_widget(titlebox)
        self.titlescroll.effect_cls = 'ScrollEffect'
        for i in range(300):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(300, 40),size_hint=(None, None))
            titlebox.add_widget(btn)

        datawindow = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', size_hint=(0.9,None) , size = (Window.width-300,Window.height-200)   )
        mainwindow.add_widget(datawindow)

        self.datescroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(0.9,None),size=(Window.width-300,100),do_scroll=True)
        self.datescroll.bind(scroll_x=self.my_x_callbackdate)
        self.datescroll.effect_cls = 'ScrollEffect'
        datawindow.add_widget(self.datescroll)
        datebox = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', padding=[10,10,10,0], spacing=10,size_hint=(None, None), height=100)
        datebox.bind(minimum_width=datebox.setter('width'))
        self.datescroll.add_widget(datebox)
        for i in range(300):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(300, 40),size_hint=(None, None))
            datebox.add_widget(btn)


        self.datascroll = ScrollView(size_hint=(0.9,None),size=(Window.width-300,Window.height-250),do_scroll=True)
        self.datascroll.bind(scroll_y=self.my_y_callback)
        self.datascroll.bind(scroll_x=self.my_x_callback)
        self.datascroll.effect_cls = 'ScrollEffect'
        self.datascroll.scrolldistance = 0
        self.datascroll.smooth_scroll_end = 0

        datawindow.add_widget(self.datascroll)
        databox = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=[10,10,10,10], spacing=10,size_hint=(None, None))
        databox.bind(minimum_height=databox.setter('height'))
        databox.bind(minimum_width=databox.setter('width'))

        self.datascroll.add_widget(databox)
        for i in range(300):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(3000, 40),size_hint=(None, None))
            databox.add_widget(btn)
        #self.titlescroll.scroll_b = self.datascroll
        #self.titlescroll.scroll_y = self.titlescroll.scroll_b.scroll_y

    def my_y_callback(self,value,x):
        self.titlescroll.scroll_y = self.datascroll.scroll_y

    def my_x_callback(self,value,x):
        self.datescroll.scroll_x= self.datascroll.scroll_x

    def my_y_callbacktitle(self,value,x):
        self.datascroll.scroll_y = self.titlescroll.scroll_y

    def my_x_callbackdate(self,value,x):
        self.datascroll.scroll_x= self.datescroll.scroll_x


class trialapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root()

trialapp().run()
```